# Parsing HTML DOM in web worker

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon, web-worker

I am trying to extract content from web pages using my firefox/chrome/safari extension. Capturing works fine but when I capture full web pages, it takes a long time and UI gets blocked. I want to move the capture/DOM parsing code to a different thread (Web Worker). But web workers do not have access to the DOM. Is there a way I can work around this?

I am using the following code to inject the script into the web page:

```
function executeScript(script, messageKey, callback) {
        var wm = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);
        var mainWindow = wm.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");
        mainWindow.gBrowser.selectedBrowser.messageManager.loadFrameScript(script, true);
        mainWindow.gBrowser.selectedBrowser.messageManager.addMessageListener(messageKey, callback);
    }

executeScript("chrome://extension/content/contentscript.js", "onSelectionReceived", onSelection);
```

All the DOM processing is happening inside this script 'contentscript.js'

Comment: What do you mean by "extracting" here?

Comment: I am trying to get the html data from the web page that is open in the current tab. I am injecting a script into the web page using the following api in firefox: http://pastebin.com/bzMnrnJ2

Comment: How would you like the data to look once its been parsed?

Comment: @Jake I am injecting the script in the web page and then trying to send a JSON object with the processed data. Each attribute in the JSON object is a string. The problem is that I cannot access the DOM in the web worker. If there is an alternative to this. Please suggest.

Comment: @quad_damage: No, accessing DOM has to happen on the main thread. So you should probably ask about improving your capturing code in such a way that it doesn't block the UI, not about using web workers for something that they cannot do.

Comment: @WladimirPalant Thank you. I have updated my question. Could you help in figuring out how to optimize this? Is this the right way to do it? In the contentscript.js file, I am traversing the DOM to extract the HTML content.

Comment: If all the info you need is in document.body.innerHTML you could send that over as a string to the worker and process it into JSON there. You might also be able to parse it back into some kind of DOM with something like phantomJS if you want to reuse your old code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the work you are trying to perform needs to interact with the DOM and it happens to take a long time, and you can't refactor it to not *need* to interact with the DOM, then there is a way without using WebWorkers.

(Because as you discovered, WebWorkers do not have access to the DOM)

Consider using Array Processing.   The basic idea is to split up the work you need to do into different chunks, and after reach chunk of work is completed, periodically give back control to the DOM (UI Thread) using the Timer.

Here is a basic example of Array Processing:

```
function saveDocument(id){
    var tasks = [openDocument,writeText,closeDocument,updateUI]

    setTimeout(function(){

        //execute the next task
        var task = tasks.shift();
        task(id);

        //determine if there's more
        if (tasks.length > 0) {
            setTimeout(arguments.calee, 25);
        }
    }, 25);
}
```

Comment: The term `Array Processing` really has nothing to do with this approach. The core of how this solution is helpful is because it's using `asynchronous execution`

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer Technically you might be correct with the terminology.  But I feel as though you are splitting hairs, since I did explain in layman's terms that after each chunk of work to give back control to the DOM using a timeout.

Comment: Your solution in it self is fine, my point is that you shouldn't introduce terminology that doesn't exists. You could use this feedback to improve your question and perhaps even earn my upvote.